# How to close form after MessageBox shows up three times?

Tags: c#, forms, if-statement

So I started writing this simple code that will ask for a name and only "adam" works anything else won't. But I want it to close the form after three failed attempts

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
     int Counter = 0;

     if (textBox1.Text == "adam"){
         MessageBox.Show("hello, " + textBox1.Text);
     } else if (textBox1.Text != "adam"){
         MessageBox.Show("Please write the correct name. As " + textBox1.Text + " is not correct");
         Counter++;
     } else if (Counter ==3){
         this.Close();
     }
```

I've tried "else if" statements and "If" but nothing seems to work

Comment: ```if (Counter ==3) { this.Close();  }```  apply this condition top of the page

Comment: sorry but the if statement would be checked no matter the order so putting at the top wouldn't work I tried it and got the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either your `if (textBox1.Text == "adam")` or your `else if (textBox1.Text != "adam")` will always be true; the user either did write, or did not write, "adam" int he box. This means that either the `if` is entered, or the first `else if` is entered.

Your code will never check `else if (Counter ==3)` because it will always find something true sooner

Perhaps you should disconnect the `if(Counter` check from the other checks (remove the `else` and make it its own `if`):

```
    if (textBox1.Text == "adam")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("hello, " + textBox1.Text);
    }
    else if (textBox1.Text != "adam")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please write the correct name. As " + textBox1.Text + " is not correct");
        Counter++;
    }
  
    if (Counter ==3)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
```

And also, **do not declare `Counter` in the `button2_Click`**, declare it in the class:

```
public class YourFormNameHere: Form{

  public int Counter {get;set;} = 0;

  ...
```

Side note: naming conventions for C#; if declared in a method (like you currently have) it should be called `int counter = 0`. If it's in the top of a class and is public, call it `Counter`, if it's private or protected, call it `_counter`. If it's public, make it a property (`get;set;`), not a field

---

Edit:

Here's how the whole thing should look:

```
public class YOUR_CLASS_NAME_HERE: Form{

    public int Counter {get;set;} = 0;

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        if (textBox1.Text == "adam")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("hello, " + textBox1.Text);
        }
        else if (textBox1.Text != "adam")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please write the correct name. As " + textBox1.Text + " is not correct");
            Counter++;
        }
      
        if (Counter ==3)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

<sub>Actually, it should also use helpful names for variables, like `usernameTextBox` or `LoginButton_Click` - always take the time to rename your controls after you drop them on a form</sub>

Comment: But it did the same thing

Comment: I am just confused since the statement almost looks like its not being checked

Comment: Write "paul" in the box and click your Login (or whatever) button 3 times. You should get 3 messageboxes in a ow saying "Please write.." and then the form closes.. Unless you reset Counter to 0 somewhere else

Comment: Oh.. Just noticed (because it wasn't in the code block due to a formatting problem) that you declare `Counter=0` every time you click the button. It will never reach 3. 1) don't declare Counter here, declare it in the top of the class (like it should be, as your naming of it using a capital C implies)

Comment: No, I've just noticed that it doesn't add forever => it starts at 0 every time you click the button

Comment: When I input it before the method of Button Click it states that it couldn't find the variable Counter i

Comment: It won't if you declare it at the top of the class. I edited my answer to show you how

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean I am a beginner so I am trying to get the hang of it

Comment: Nevermind I got it working thanks for the help